# Scraping public data with migration

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scraping public data from UNHCR web site.

[image]

All data which I want are stored here in button marked with yellow circle. If I press on this button with left click of mouse I will all data which is necessary for me in csv format.

But I want to download all data directly in R and I press right button of the mouse and I copy link address and put into this line of code

```
    # Dataset for scraping 
        https://www.unhcr.org/refugee-statistics/download/?url=E1ZxP4 
        
download.file(url = "https://api.unhcr.org/population/v1/population/?download=true#_ga=2.69829909.40031775.1622553152-198173155.1622026343", 
                              destfile = "C:/Users/User/Documents/Work/Data/DataScraping/Test/test.txt", mode = "wb")
```

At the end I downloads data but is not data which I expected, so can anybody help me how to solve this and download csv directly into R ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the data in JSON format via an API, as you might notice from inspecting the website's XHR files on the Network tab of the Inspect panel.

(Right-click this page and inspect it for fun!)

Try this code:

```
library(jsonlite)

# Base URL
url <- 'https://api.unhcr.org/population/v1/population/?'

# Query items
query_list = list(limit=100,
                  dataset='population',
                  displayType='totals',
                  'columns%5B%5D'='refugees',
                  'columns%5B%5D'='asylum_seekers',
                  'columns%5B%5D'='idps',
                  'columns%5B%5D'='vda',
                  'columns%5B%5D'='stateless',
                  'columns%5B%5D'='ooc',
                  yearFrom=1951,
                  yearTo=2020)

# Concatenates the query items to the base URL 
for (idx in seq_along(query_list)) {
  item_name <- names(query_list[idx])
  item_val <- query_list[[idx]]
  url <- paste0(url, item_name, '=', item_val, '&')
}

# Removes last character, i.e. &
url <- substr(url, 1, nchar(url)-1)

# Encodes URL to avoid errors
url <- URLencode(url)

# Extracts JSON from URL
json_extract <- fromJSON(url)

# Converts relevant list into a data.frame
df <- data.frame(json_extract[['items']])
```

Notice that the original request query had a limit of 20 results. The only change I made to it was to increase this limit to 100, which then returns all data at once.

The resulting data.frame's structure is the following:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   70 obs. of  15 variables:
  $ year          : int  1951 1952 1953 1954 1955 1956 1957 1958 1959 1960 ...
$ coo_id        : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ coo_name      : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ coo           : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ coo_iso       : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ coa_id        : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ coa_name      : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ coa           : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ coa_iso       : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ refugees      : int  2116011 1952928 1847304 1749628 1717966 1767975 1742514 1698310 1674185 1656664 ...
$ asylum_seekers: chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
$ idps          : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
$ vda           : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ stateless     : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
```

And here is its summary:

```
> summary(df)
      year         coo_id            coo_name             coo           
 Min.   :1951   Length:70          Length:70          Length:70         
 1st Qu.:1968   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Median :1986   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :1986                                                           
 3rd Qu.:2003                                                           
 Max.   :2020                                                           
                                                                        
   coo_iso             coa_id            coa_name             coa           
 Length:70          Length:70          Length:70          Length:70         
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
                                                                            
                                                                            
                                                                            
                                                                            
   coa_iso             refugees        asylum_seekers         idps          
 Length:70          Min.   : 1656664   Length:70          Length:70         
 Class :character   1st Qu.: 2924617   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Median :10098181   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
                    Mean   : 8862333                                        
                    3rd Qu.:12507743                                        
                    Max.   :20676358                                        
                                                                            
      vda           stateless             ooc           
 Min.   :2592947   Length:70          Length:70         
 1st Qu.:3087436   Class :character   Class :character  
 Median :3581926   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :3252358                                        
 3rd Qu.:3582064                                        
 Max.   :3582202                                        
 NA's   :67
```